Grpc service unavailable with kafka topic with many partitions
In our system we use gRPC as a server-server way of connection and kafka for async interraction. And I found one curious case when gRPC service is unavailable, only grpc while http spring actuator works. By using Postman I'm trying to call my gRPC service, but it doesn't respond.

After a while my gRPC server starts answering, but this gab between "false" readiness and real readiness is different and I didn't find any relations to other settings or libraries in my app.

In the second pic we see 3 seconds between "false" and real readiness. In the real app this gab could last for two or more minutes.
This behavior appears only in my app with gRPC server and kafka with one or more topics with many partitions( > 100). When I tried to investigate it I found nothing which could explain this situation. Logs didn't tell me anything interesting even in trace mode, no exceptions or warnings.
To reproduce it I have created a simple app https://github.com/Danneborg/PsGrpcSimpleServerApplication.
Steps to do for reproducing.

Download the project.
Run kafka server in your ps.
Create 2 topics in kafka with 200 partitions.
Override properties topicOne, topicTwo and kafkaUrl in application.properties

Start the app first time and create a sample message in postman

Run app first time, try to send message. If it goes well then stop and run again. Because this app is super light this curious behavior appears on 4th or 5th rerun. Usually first run goes well, but when you rerun it this problem starts to appear.

